# JQuery condition with blank input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do multiple checks in a jquery condition ...

I am looking for something like this:

IF checkbox_A is Checked then

If input_A is empty then alert('input_A is Required')

else Add a class="continue" to the div below.

```
<button id="btn1">Continue</button>
```

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally wouldn't do this as you haven't even shown an attempt to write any code yourself, but I'm in a good mood.

```
if ($("#checkboxA").is(":checked")) {
    if ($("#inputA").val() == "") {
        alert("input_A is required");
    }
    else {
        $("#btn1").addClass("continue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("#yourCheckBoxId").is(":checked")) {
     if($("#yourInputId").val() == "") {
          alert("empty");
     } 
     else {
        $("button[id='btn1']").addClass("continue");
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
if ( document.getElementById('checkbox_A').checked ){
  if (document.getElementById('input_A').value == ''){
    alert('input_A is Required')
  } else {
    $('#btn1').addClass('continue;);
  }
}
```

---

But if you have multiple elements you want to validate you can avoid manual checking of each field and automate by adding an `required` class to the element that are required..

```
<input type="text" name="...." class="required" />
```

now when you want to validate the form you do

```
// find the required elements that are empty
var fail = $('.required').filter(function(){return this.value == ''});
// if any exist
if (fail.length){
  // get their names
  var fieldnames = fail.map(function(){return this.name;}).get().join('\n');
  // inform the user
  alert('The fields \n\n' + fieldnames + '\n\n are required');
  // focus on the first empty one so the user can fill it..
  fail.first().focus();
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/523wR/

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible:

```
$('#checkBoxA').click(function() {
var checkBoxA = $('#checkBoxA');
var textBoxA = $('#textBoxA');

if (checkBoxA.checked())
{
    if (textBoxA.val() == "")
    {
        $('#btn1').removeClass('continue');
        alert("No value entered");
        textBoxA.focus();
    }
    else {
        $('#btn1').addClass('continue');
    }
} else {
    $('#btn1').addClass('continue');
}
});
```